# Help to choose right file system type to create

Tags: server, partitioning, filesystem, lvm, ext4

I need help about a file system creation on Ubuntu server 21.10 installed on a virtual machine hosted on vmware environment.
In particular I'm like to know which kind of FS I should use for my necessities.
Let me resume below the details of my scenario:
The filesystem will be created on a single device of 1350GB size and will have multiple folders on it (about 30 thousand folders)
More small files are continuously written into these folders (thousands of files every minute with size from 5 to 20MB compressed)
and these files will be decompressed in realtime (always on the same filesystem) and then are taken from other systems (by sftp)
This flow is continuous 24 hours a day.

In addition, once a day, 5 larger files are written (about 2Gb compressed) which are however managed (unzip and processing phase) on other servers

This filesystem in the future may need to be extended but never shrunk.

I was thinking of using EXT4 on LVM, what do you think? I would need a file system that has excellent performance

Many Thanks,
Daniele

Comment: This is an opinion based question so you won’t get much response. Linux Format magazine did a comparison of file systems in the December 2021 issue. They named XFS top with ext4 second. Both were rated 10/10. I’ve only had experience with ext4 and it is excellent. LVM will allow flexibility so ext4 on LVM is a solid choice.

Comment: Really thanks PonJar for your support